# populate dropdown list with dojo ajax

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, dojo

hey i am using the following code to make cascading dropdown in which , i made one function xyz() in which am ajax is called who call a servlet and set the value in result variable , the value in result is in separated by comma so i split it with comma and the store into second drop down .. now the problem is when i change the 1st dropdown 2nd dropdown is not populated but the ajax is called , and when i change the value second time then 2nd dropdwn is populate with wrong value which is i select previews .. please tell me whats wrong

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="js/dojo/dijit/themes/claro/document.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="js/dojo/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css" />
    <script src='js/dojo/dojo/dojo.js' data-dojo-config=' parseOnLoad: true'></script>
    <script>
        dojo.require("dijit.form.ComboBox");
        dojo.require("dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore");
        dojo.require("dojo.ready");
        dojo.require("dojo.store.Memory");
        require(["dojo/parser", "dijit/form/ComboBox","dijit/form/TextBox","dojo/dom-construct"]);
     function xyz(){
      dojo.xhrPost({
            // The URL to request
            url: "populate",
            timeout :  3000 ,
            content: {
                username: document.getElementById("state").value

            },

            load: function(result) {                
         require(["dijit/form/ComboBox", "dojo/ready","dojo/store/Memory"], 
                function(ComboBox,ready,Memory){

                    ready(function() {

                        dojo.connect(dijit.byId('state'), 'onChange', function() {

                            var stateSelect = dijit.byId('stateSelect');

                            if (!stateSelect) {
                                stateSelect = new ComboBox({id: "stateSelect",name:"select",value: "Select",searchAttr:"name"},"stateSelect");

                            }

                            var str_array = result.split(',');

                            var data = [];
                            dojo.forEach(str_array, function(item, idx) {
                                data.push({
                                    id: idx,
                                    name: item                    
                                });
                                stateSelect.set('store', new Memory({data: data}));


                            });


                        }); // dojo.connect



                    }); // ready   



                }); // require  

        }



      });

    }


    </script>
</head>
<body class="claro">

    <select data-dojo-type="dijit.form.ComboBox" id="state" name="state" onchange="xyz()"  >

        <option selected>Andaman Nicobar</option>
        <option>Andhra Pradesh</option>
        <option>Arunachal Pradesh</option>


    </select>

    <select data-dojo-type="dijit.form.ComboBox" id="stateSelect" name="stateSelect">

    </select>


</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason that stateSelect is populated on second try is that you use dojo.connect which just binds onChange event on state to callback which does the job of populating stateSelect.

Remove dojo.connect. You do not need that.

To get the corrent value you should do something like this
you should use dijit registry and go `registry.byId("state").get("value")`
instead of `document.getElementById("state").value`

Also you probably want to use FilteringSelect here, see differences:
Difference is explained here http://kennethfranqueiro.com/2010/06/combobox-vs-filteringselect/

Also some more info:

Instead of `xhrPost` use `dojo.request` module

Instead of `onchange=xyz()` you can add event handler when dom is ready with your function as callback